Assignment operator overloading is being bypassed when trying to copy a class instance
I have the following example from a course, about Deep Copying:
#include <iostream>

class DeepCopy
{
private:
    int *_myInt;

public:
    DeepCopy(int val)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *_myInt = val;
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << std::endl;
    }
    ~DeepCopy()
    {
        free(_myInt);
        std::cout << "resource freed at address " << _myInt << std::endl;
    }
    DeepCopy(DeepCopy &source)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *_myInt = *source._myInt;
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << " with _myInt = " << *_myInt << std::endl;
    }
    DeepCopy &operator=(DeepCopy &source)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << " with _myInt=" << *_myInt << std::endl;
        *_myInt = *source._myInt;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DeepCopy source(42);
    DeepCopy dest1(source);
    DeepCopy dest2 = dest1;

    return 0;
}

The output from the above is:
resource allocated at address 0x13c3c20
resource allocated at address 0x13c4050 with _myInt = 42
resource allocated at address 0x13c4070 with _myInt = 42
resource freed at address 0x13c4070
resource freed at address 0x13c4050
resource freed at address 0x13c3c20

This seems like it's doing what it should, but when I play around with the code, it looks like the last line in main() DeepCopy dest2 = dest1; is not actually executing the code in the operator overloading function.
For example, I tried adding std::cout << "hello\n"; to the operator overloading function, and the string "hello" was not output to the terminal when I ran the program. Another time, I commented out the entire operator overloading function block, and the code still compiled and ran just fine.
It looks like the line DeepCopy dest2 = dest1; is actually executing the copy constructor twice, because when I rewrote the copy constructor to the following (I added the last line):
   DeepCopy(DeepCopy &source)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *_myInt = *source._myInt;
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << " with _myInt = " << *_myInt << std::endl;
        std::cout << "hello 2 \n";
    }

the program outputs:
resource allocated at address 0x167bc20
resource allocated at address 0x167c050 with _myInt = 42
hello 2 
resource allocated at address 0x167c070 with _myInt = 42
hello 2 
resource freed at address 0x167c070
resource freed at address 0x167c050
resource freed at address 0x167bc20

My question is: Why is the operator overloading function not being invoked in the above code, when it looks like it should be? Why is the copy constructor being executed twice?
I've looked through many similar stackoverflow questions but cannot seem to find the answer.

It's simple: DeepCopy dest2 = dest1; is not an assignment, it's construction. Assignment needs an already constructed object on the left. Try DeepCopy dest2; dest2 = dest1;.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Side note: your operator= is leaking memory as it is not free'ing the old int before replacing it with a new int (also, why are you using malloc in C++? Use new and delete instead). In any case, the operator doesn't actually need to reallocate memory at all, it can just copy the source int's value into the existing allocated int.

"It looks like the line DeepCopy dest2 = dest1; is actually executing the copy constructor twice," -- Your conclusion ignores the line before this. Comment out this line to see what its actual effect is. By the way, adding more output to assignment and copy construction was a good idea. However, I would have changed the existing output so that the lines are not identical in assignment and construction.

Also, DeepCopy &operator=(DeepCopy &source) s/b DeepCopy &operator=(const DeepCopy &source) This allows assignment from both lvalues and rvalues.
